# wrong rasterization of polygon values

Tags: r, terra

I have a shapefile with multiple polygons, each of which is coded as 0 (green) or 1 (purple) and I want to rasterize it to a defined grid (`template.rast`):

```
r = rasterize(shp, template.rast, "comp_cat_cl", touches=TRUE)
```

I assumed that leaving `fun=NULL` operates assigning to the cell the value of the most abundant value/polygon in the pixel...but if I check, it doesn't seem so.
As shown in the image below, some pixels in which the abundance of green (i.e. 0) is visibly higher, get rasterized as 1 (blue pixel) instead of 0 (pink pixel) [The same happens in the opposite way but it's not shown in the image].

[image]

As a crosscheck, I tried to dissolve the polygons by value but the result is the same.
It's a pretty simple operation but I don't understand where the error is.
(I'm using `terra 1.7-23` on W10.)

Comment: I found out this other thread but using the solution proposed by Robert returns only a handful of pixel (but correct, where comparable ): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71065269/rasterize-polygons-based-on-maximum-overlap-using-r-packages-terra-or-stars

Comment: As an alternative you could first rasterize at a significantly higher resolution (perhaps with touches = FALSE), then use `terra::aggregate()` with `fun = "modal"` to get the most prominent polygon value in each cell.